# How to get all groups that are required to access files under a directory?

Tags: perl

I have some main directory. I use the following code to get the group name of the directory:

```
my ($gid) = getgrgid(stat($file)->gid);
```

By group I mean the group which you see when you run `ls -la` on the directory.

I want to find all the group names which are required to access the file under the main directory.
So for example if `/a/b/c` has group `g1` and under `c` there are `/e/f`, which require group `g2` and `g/h` which require group `g3`, then I want to say:

```
{
    "a/b/c": ["g1", "g2", "g3"]
}
```

Is there some module or some clean way to do this in Perl?

Comment: So you're asking how to iterate over the contents of a directory? File::Find::Rule

Comment: I thought about using `Find` but it will take a lot of time if areas are big. I thought there would be some "trick' or module which does it quite fast

Comment: Well, either you want to visit all entries or you don't...

Answer (score 3):

Use [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find) to traverse the subdirectories. If you store the groups in a hash, they won't be duplicated and they won't consume so much memory.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Find qw{ find };
use File::stat;

my %groups;
find(sub {
    undef $groups{ stat($_)->gid };
}, shift);
say join ' ', map scalar getgrgid($_), keys %groups;
```

I noticed you are interested in a particular single file, not everything under the given path. In that case, you need to climb upwards the directories:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::stat;
use Path::Tiny qw{ path };

my ($path, $top) = map path($_)->absolute, @ARGV;

my %groups;

while (1) {
    undef $groups{ stat($path)->gid };
    last if $path eq $top || $path eq 'Path::Tiny'->rootdir;
    $path = $path->parent->absolute;
}
say join ' ', map scalar getgrgid($_), keys %groups;
```

I used [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) for convenience, but you can use [File::Spec](http://p3rl.org/File::Spec), too.

Comment: `getgrgid` on every entry might amount to a significant time-sink; you could get all the gids into a hash and then do `map getgrgid` after.

Comment: @hobbs: You're probably right, but when I try it, the difference is on the edge of measurability.

Comment: No problem, just a vagrant thought, since OP was pretty concerned about performance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the file, start with that. Then, remove the base name of the file and try again. Work your way until you are at the top:

```
my %groups;
my $file = '/a/b/c/file.txt';
my ($gid) = getgrgid(stat($file)->gid);
$groups{ $gid }++;
```

Now get the next highest level and do the same thing:

```
use File::Basename;
$file = dirname($file);
$gid = ...;
$groups{ $gid }++;
```

At the end, the hash keys are all the groups involved.

People have focussed on the issue of visiting all files in a directory tree, but I didn't notice that requirement in your question.